# How do draw FormattedText (if not in the onRender method)

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I draw some Ellipse and add them to a Grid.

Then I'd like to add some FormattedText to each Ellipse. This i could do by getting the RectangleBounds of the Ellipse.

But following this example:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613560.aspx#FormattedText_Object

I need a DrawingContext to draw the text. But if I don't wantto override onRender, how can I get a DrawingContext?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a `DrawingGroup` instead. It has an `Open` method that returns a `DrawingContext` and you can use that to construct a drawing.

You'll then need to arrange for that drawing to appear in the UI somehow. The easiest way is to wrap it in a `DrawingBrush` and use that to paint some existing element in the UI. For example, if you've got an ellipse called `myEllipse`, this will set its `Fill` property to be a `DrawingBrush` based on a `DrawingGroup` that contains a single bit of `FormattedText`:

```
var drawing = new DrawingGroup();
using (var context = drawing.Open())
{
    var text = new FormattedText("This is some text",
        CultureInfo.CurrentCulture,
        FlowDirection.LeftToRight,
        new Typeface("Calibri"),
        30,
        Brushes.Green);
    context.DrawText(text, new Point(0, 0));
}

var db = new DrawingBrush(drawing);
db.Stretch = Stretch.None;
myEllipse.Fill = db;
```

If you've already filled the `Ellipse` with something else, you have two choices. You could either add more content to this drawing - you can make as many calls into the context as you like. For example, if I add this immediately before the call to `context.DrawText`:

```
context.DrawRectangle(Brushes.Cyan, null, new Rect(0, 0, 300, 100));
```

I'll get a cyan background behind the text. (You'd need to adjust the coordinates in these examples to suit your layout, of course.)

But it's probably simpler to add an extra element to host the drawing, rather than trying to piggy-back it into an element that's there to do something else. So you could put a `Rectangle` element positioned directly over the `Ellipse`, and use a `DrawingBrush` such as this as the `Fill` for that `Rectangle`. The `Rectangle` won't actually look rectangular, because this `DrawingBrush` doesn't paint in its whole area. So the effect will look much the same as it would if you'd layered a `TextBlock` over an `Ellipse`.